# NMAP DNS Service Detection

Tags: nmap

I was looking out how NMAP identifies DNS services. After determining that port 53 is open it issues a standard query TXT version.bind to find out if BIND is running on the domain port. Then, I saw that after NMAP received the response:

```
    9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1
```

it issued a "Server Status Request" and received a "Server Status Request Response, Not implemented" and displayed port 53 as open but did not specify a version. What is a "Server Status Request" and why did NMAP not lable the port as running BIND considering that it received the version?

Comment: You can use http://scannmap.com/nmap-dns-server-scan/ to detect DNS server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the DNS service you are probing over TCP or UDP? There is a match line that looks appropriate (line 8836 in [the latest SVN version](http://nmap.org/svn/nmap-service-probes)), but it is only matched for TCP ports. Also, the fingerprint was added on February 4, 2012, so if you are using a version earlier than 5.61TEST5, you will not detect this service properly.

Nmap's service detection database is built from user submissions. If you have a service that is not being detected correctly, make sure your Nmap is up-to-date and  re-run the version scan with these arguments:

```
nmap -v -sV --version-all -p 53 example.com
```

and follow the instructions for [submitting the fingerprint](http://nmap.org/submit).

Comment: Sounds like I should upgrade my copy of nmap, then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Server Status Requests (OPCODE 2) are a very optional part of the DNS protocol, which BIND hasn't implemented, so that response is normal.

Looking in nmap-service-probes on my own machine it doesn't look like nmap knows that "9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1" is a version of BIND. (It seems to expect BIND instances to use the word BIND in their reply.)